# Storing Extremely Long Text as Primary Key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a question about database design (I'm using PSQL, but it's more of a general question).

Is it feasible to have a ~500 character `text` as primary key? What are the major downsides of having a large key (if there is any?)

In my specific design, I have a prompt that allows them to adjust the settings (+ seed, otherwise the seed is randomly generated). With the same settings and same seed, they're able to create the same world over and over again - which is something I don't want to happen. I was thinking to just have the PKey for my table be the `settings.json` (includes the seed), to ensure its unique every time.

I can also put the `settings.json` as a non-primary key and index over it to check it fast, but it seems like it would be much slower than just setting it as PKey, otherwise PKey would just be `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Index maintenance as well as SQL-Where and Join-On performance is more or less slower.
The major downside of a ~500 character text as primary key is the multi-purpose overloading though. The original purpose of a primary key is being a unique row identifier, creating unique (big)int values via built-in auto-increment features or as uuid/guid types is easy. As soon as you add another purpose like having a 500-byte meaning, things will get really complicate all of a sudden

Comment: The ideal key is to be as narrow as possible in all but very few situations, such as the column is also the only attribute. IO performance will be sub-optimal and if it's a clustered key then all non-clustered index performance will be sub-optimal.

Comment: @Stu there is no such thing as a clustered key in Postgres. And indexes that do not include the primary key column won't be affected by the size of the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Separate from any technical limitation of using a 500-character-long primary key would be the issue of having humans try and use the primary ID. I'm unsure how your database is being used but if I was an end-user of the database and I had to query it directly, I would be pretty frustrated if I had to copy a 500-character long pk_id if I wanted to query a specific record directly.*

*Which happens quite a bit when trying QA problematic records.